# How do I send transaction from a non-sealer node/account that can be validated by a validator?

Tags: sendtransaction, geth-clique

Quick review of my system :

- Every nodes are connected through geth, clique (so a proof of authority system)
- I have a bootnode that isn't a sealer
- I have one main_node that **is** a sealer
- I have one client_node that isn't a sealer
- the last two nodes are connected through the bootnode, I can for instance deploy contract on my main node, manually copy the contractAddress, then launch a call on that contract. Everything seems to work here.

But, I can't execute a sendtransaction() from my client_node, and from my bootnode too. I can only do call(). I understand *why* but I really need some client to do some transaction on my blockchain, while having **one** node validating everything. I see few solutions to this

1. Make said client a signer, and since i want to give only specific right to specific client, this would technically be what i want. But, while tools like hyperledger.fabric looks made for this (at a first glance, for me, at the very least), clique/geth doesn't seems to handle the "single and permanent leader" concept so well. I want a way to allow specific contract related transaction to a group of signer.
2. Send a transaction through a client node that isn't allow to mine, for asking a sealer to mine the said transaction. But I don't know if it's possible, and everything that I read on this made me more and more confused about this.
3. Cheating and use another ways than blockchain to transmit a need for a specific transaction to my main node, by a website interface for instance. This isn't the method that I want, even if it looks like the best way to deal with this issue.
4. Using something else (hyperledger, for instance ?)

Could you tell me if the solution 1 and/or 2 might work for me, ways to implement it, if you see another solutions, ect. Also we use vyper contract and for now python script to launch everything, but i'm pretty sure it's not relevant here.

Comment: "But, I can't execute a sendtransaction() from my client_node, and from my bootnode too. I can only do call(). I understand why", could you share why?